# Input property not binding on attribute selector

Tags: angular

Good day,

I have the following Angular2 component:

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {NameValue} from '../models/namevalue';
import {CrmService} from '../services/crmservice';

@Component({
    selector: '[crmlookup]',
    templateUrl: '/app/directives/rendernamevalue.html'
})

export class CrmLookupComponent {
    @Input() fieldname: string;
    public values;

    constructor(public _crmService: CrmService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._crmService.get(this.fieldname).subscribe(res => this.values = res);
    }
}
```

My HTML looks as follows:

```
<select crmlookup [fieldname]="new_department"></select>
```

It binds fine, but the fieldname internal input field is never initialized with the string value I specify in the markup.

Note that new_department must be a string value, it's not a property in the parent component.  I've also tried specifying it as [fieldname]="'new_department'" which also doesn't work.  The value is undefined in the constructor as well as the ngOnInit event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to provide a string literal value for the `fieldname` input, you could try this:

```
<select crmlookup [fieldname]="'new_department'"></select>
```

or

```
<select crmlookup fieldname="new_department"></select>
```

Using `[fieldname]` will evaluate an expression based on elements of the component associated with the template.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thanks for the response, but both of those scenarios still result in the @Input() fieldname variable being undefined in both the constructor and ngOnInit() event.

Comment: Are you sure? ;-) Agreed for the constructor but not for `ngOnInit`. See this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/OYZLtURA0lLy6eNPu1Kv?p=preview.

Comment: I see what you mean, and I'll accept the answer - but strangely it still doesn't pull through.  Is it not perhaps because I'm selecting on an attribute and not an element like your example?

Comment: Strange! I updated the plunkr with an attribute selector and it seems to work as well... If you're interesting in investigating more, feel free to provide me a plunkr to reproduce and I'll have a look...

Comment: Thank you sir!!  I might have done something wrong, but it's working like this on my side now too :-)

Comment: But new_department in this case cannot be bind to a model.